# How can I align an image that is within a script and has no parent?

Tags: html, css, center, image-gallery

I want to create an image gallery where parts of the image are hidden and get displayed when clicked on. My main problem is, how can I center the image that shows up after I clicked on the cropped image? These pictures may help understanding my problem.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QX7d.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf6AG.png

This is my code so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
   
.grid-container {
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 1400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;

}
   
   .little-finger-klein {
    height: 300px;
    width:  700px;
    background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/little-finger-klein.png') no-repeat;
    }

   .little-finger-gross {
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width:  1400px;
    background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/little-finger-ganz.png') no-repeat;
    
   }

   .justate-klein {  
    height: 300px;
    width:  700px;
    background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/just-ate-klein.png') no-repeat;

   }

   .justate-gross {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 600px;
    width:  1400px;
    background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/just-ate-ganz.png') no-repeat;

   }

   .socket-klein {
   height: 300px;
   width:  700px;
   background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/socket-klein.png') no-repeat;
   }

   .socket-gross {
    position: absolute;
    left: 8px;
    top: 8px;
   height: 600px;
   width: 1400px;
   background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/socket-ganz.png') no-repeat;
   }

   .pitschi-klein {
    height: 300px;
    width:  700px;
   background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/pitschi-klein.png') no-repeat;
   }

   .pitschi-gross {
    position: absolute;
    left: 8px;
    top: 8px;
   height: 600px;
   width: 1400px;
   background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/pitschi-ganz.png') no-repeat;
   }

</style>
  <title>Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="column">
    <div id="littlefingerklein" class="little-finger-klein"></div>
    <div id="socketklein" class="socket-klein"></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div id="justateklein" class="justate-klein"></div>
    <div id="pitschiklein" class="pitschi-klein"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  var light = document.getElementById('littlefingerklein');

  light.addEventListener('click', function(light){
      light.target.classList.toggle('little-finger-gross');
  })
  
  var light2 = document.getElementById('justateklein');
  
  light2.addEventListener('click', function(light2){
      light2.target.classList.toggle('justate-gross');
  })
  
  var light3 = document.getElementById('socketklein');
  
  light3.addEventListener('click', function(light3){
      light3.target.classList.toggle('socket-gross');
  })
  
  var light4 = document.getElementById('pitschiklein');
  
  light4.addEventListener('click', function(light4){
      light4.target.classList.toggle('pitschi-gross');
  })
  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images do in fact have a parent, they are in the DOM and are just referred to in the script. If you want to position them in the same place you can use `position: absolute` like you've already done but need to also specify `top: 0` and `left: 0` to move them to the right place.

Note that `position: absolute` will position the elements inside their closest parent that doesn't have the default `position: static` property set. To anchor them in the same place, you can change their common parent `.grid-container` to something else, like `position: relative`. This will cause all child elements with `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` to be aligned to the grid container's top left corner.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
   
.grid-container {
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 1400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  position: relative;

}
   
   .little-finger-klein {
    height: 300px;
    width:  700px;
    background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/little-finger-klein.png') no-repeat;
    }

   .little-finger-gross {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 600px;
    width: 1400px;
    background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/little-finger-ganz.png') no-repeat;
    
   }

   .justate-klein {  
    height: 300px;
    width:  700px;
    background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/just-ate-klein.png') no-repeat;

   }

   .justate-gross {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 600px;
    width: 1400px;
    background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/just-ate-ganz.png') no-repeat;

   }

   .socket-klein {
   height: 300px;
   width:  700px;
   background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/socket-klein.png') no-repeat;
   }

   .socket-gross {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
   height: 600px;
   width: 1400px;
   background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/socket-ganz.png') no-repeat;
   }

   .pitschi-klein {
    height: 300px;
    width:  700px;
   background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/pitschi-klein.png') no-repeat;
   }

   .pitschi-gross {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
   height: 600px;
   width: 1400px;
   background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/pitschi-ganz.png') no-repeat;
   }

</style>
  <title>Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="column">
    <div id="littlefingerklein" class="little-finger-klein"></div>
    <div id="socketklein" class="socket-klein"></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div id="justateklein" class="justate-klein"></div>
    <div id="pitschiklein" class="pitschi-klein"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  var light = document.getElementById('littlefingerklein');

  light.addEventListener('click', function(light){
      light.target.classList.toggle('little-finger-gross');
  })
  
  var light2 = document.getElementById('justateklein');
  
  light2.addEventListener('click', function(light2){
      light2.target.classList.toggle('justate-gross');
  })
  
  var light3 = document.getElementById('socketklein');
  
  light3.addEventListener('click', function(light3){
      light3.target.classList.toggle('socket-gross');
  })
  
  var light4 = document.getElementById('pitschiklein');
  
  light4.addEventListener('click', function(light4){
      light4.target.classList.toggle('pitschi-gross');
  })
  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you!
Do you happen to know how to get this responsive?
It's important that there are always two images in one column and row!

Comment: Sure! You'll need to replace the pixel sizes such as `height: 300px` with something responsive like percentages. To make the images scale as well you'll need to explore the `background-size` property. Here's a great resource for that: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/